# gpresult group membership incorrect

Tags: group-policy

I have deployed a printer for each user of one group via print server.

When I add person to this group and just run the command " *gpupdate /force* ", I can see the printer appeared on Devices and Printers, then I removed the user form group and ran " *gpupdate /force* " the printer still exists.

Restarting system doesn't resolve this. And it's so strange that `gpresult /v /scope user` returns that the user is still a group member.

Does any one know what the reason is ?

Comment: What are the settings of the policy? I usually have deployed printer GPOs to computer objects, not users. Also, there should be something like "remove this printer when policy is no longer applied". Is that checked?

Comment: As with Yanzzee said checked that it is set to remove printer when the object falls out of scope. Security groups are funny things sometimes, general rule of thumb I always do is getting users to log out and back in to apply group membership changes as they can be flaky.